# query foreignkey field from other field which is foreign key to other

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-orm

I have model 3 models model 1 2 and 3 i need to access model 1 from model 3 model 2 has foreign key relation with model 1 and model 3 to model 2 how can access model 3 to model 1

```
class Record(models.Model):
    name = model.CharField(max_length=255)

class Task(model.Model):
    name = models.CharField('Record')
    record = models.ForeignKey(max_length, related_name='tasks')

class Subtask(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField()
    subtask_of = models.Foreignkey('Task', related_name=subtasks)
```

I need to access the record name from Subtask how can i achieve that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To filter `Subtask` by the related `Record.name` use double-underscores to follow the relationships

```
exact_matches = SubTask.objects.filter(subtask_of__record__name='foo')
partial_matches = SubTask.objects.filter(subtask_of__record__name__icontains='foo')
```

To access `Record.name` follow the foreign keys from your `Subtask` object

```
subtask_obj.subtask_of.record.name
```

Comment: I need to query it with SubTask.objects.filter()

Comment: i am trying to accept the answer pls wait brother it says u cant accept the answer in 4 minutes